# Fixed-size array that contains multiple specific types?

Tags: arrays, go

I have an array (coming from JSON) that always contains a string and an int, like so: `["foo",42]`

Right now, I have to use `[]interface{}` with assertions `arr[0].(string)` `arr[1].(int)`

I'm wondering if there's any way to specify the types expected in the array? I'm picturing something like.. `[...]{string,int}`

Thanks.

Comment: You can add runtime type assertions.  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions.  You're using the first form of type assertions, but you can also check whether the assertion succeeds or fails.  Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015753/serialize-to-json-a-mixed-type-array-in-go/28016508#28016508

Comment: Yes that is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Wouldn't this better be done with a struct type and an attached `UnmarshalJSON` method (so that it can handle the `[]` vs `{}` difference)?

Answer (score 1):

At the first, answer is No. But you can get values from `interface{}` with type you expected.
How about this?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mattn/go-scan"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    text := `["foo", 42]`

    var v interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(text), &v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var key string
    var val int
    e1, e2 := scan.ScanTree(v, "[0]", &key), scan.ScanTree(v, "[1]", &val)
    if e1 != nil || e2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(e1, e2)
    }
    fmt.Println(key, val)
}
```